# Why session ends automatically

Tags: asp.net, session

We have done a project so far it works fine but from yesterday we are having a strange problem i.e `sessions` ends automatically and even some time `authentication` fails before configured time. Some time after performing some operations like `button_click` or `dropdown_selectedIndex` session automatically ends. We have not written any code in those events to kill a `session` why this is happening can any one tell please

A sample of my `web.config`

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
   <forms loginUrl="Default.aspx" defaultUrl="cliMainPage.aspx"
    timeout="10" />

  <caching>
<outputCacheSettings>
<outputCacheProfiles>
<add name="profile" duration="30" enabled="true" varyByParam="pageNumber"/>
</outputCacheProfiles>
</outputCacheSettings>
</caching>
```

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you are using in-process session storage -

Is the application pool restarting? If you hit memory limits, or the worker process crashes, you'll lose all cache and session data. All users may be logged out.

ASP.NET has a built-in performance counter that tracks when the application restarts. Check here for details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972959.aspx#monitor_perf_topic8

Comment: Actually the issue is some thing strange here working well on my PC but the same not working on another machine. why this is happening

Comment: @Dorababu we need a lot more information than that to help troubleshoot.